# In React, why is it rendered twice in some cases?

Tags: reactjs

In the article [You Probably Don't Need Derived State](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#what-about-memoization), there is the following:

> Refs can be useful in certain cases like this one, but generally we
> recommend you use them sparingly. Even in the demo, this imperative
> method is nonideal because two renders will occur instead of one.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-org-when-to-use-derived-state-alternative-pattern-3-forked-y52wy?file=/UncontrolledEmailInput.js)

What causes React to render twice, and why it is rendered twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant section of code is:

```js
handleChange = (index) => {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex: index }, () => {
      const selectedAccount = this.props.accounts[index];
      this.inputRef.current.resetEmailForNewUser(selectedAccount.email);
    });
  };
```

The first re-render happens due to changing the state `selectedIndex` which in turn will change `selectedAccount`. Because of that the prop `defaultEmail` is going to change, triggering a re-render of `UncontrolledEmailInput`.

```js
const selectedAccount = accounts[selectedIndex];

<UncontrolledEmailInput
   defaultEmail={selectedAccount.email}
   ref={this.inputRef}
/>
```

Once the `setState` is finished, the callback that is passed will be executed, which ends up calling `resetEmailForNewUser`

```js
resetEmailForNewUser(defaultEmail) {
  this.setState({ email: defaultEmail });
}
```

This time there is state change, triggering the second re-render of `UncontrolledEmailInput`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, Any Re-renders will be a side effect from the change in state, props, props from the common store. Also, any change to ref will also render a shallow re-rendering of the component.